# VB.net BC30738 'Sub Main' is declared more than once in <application> My.MyApplication.Main(args As String())

Tags: program-entry-point, startup

Solved this issue and posting to help future readers.  This happened when switching a Windows Forms App to start with my own Main() instead of a form.  After experimenting with many different ways of correcting the issue, I ultimately resolved it by accessing the project's properties (My Project) area -> Application -> Check the box Use Application Framework.  This will change the startup object to a form.  Now uncheck the Use Application Framework box and select your Sub Main which you've already created.  This seems like a bug with visual studio (I'm running 2019) and the convoluted workaround deserved a post.

Changing a Windows Forms App to use Sub Main rather than a form should build correctly, results in duplicate Sub Main error BC30738.